# window height with content added dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        p++;
        loadImages(p);
    }
});
```

Im adding images dynamically each time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. But this only works the first time you reach bottom. Is there any way to update te document height? Or how do i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a rounding issue.  Instead of strict `==` you may want to check if it's minus a few pixels.  That may help since you can then load images before they even get all the way to the bottom.